# How to disable continuos autofocus during video shooting with Canon SX230 HS?

Tags: canon, focus

I have a Canon SX230 HS camera and want to record a movie from a train driver's perspective on a model railway.

Everything is working fine, except that the camera refocuses continuously during the shoot, making your eyes hurt when watching the movie.

Is there any way to disable the continuous autofocus when recording a movie?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about audio-video production.

Comment: The SX230 HS may be photography equipment, but as soon as you start using it for video it becomes video equipment, and not photo equipment, and this question is about the video aspects of the camera, no the photography aspects, and so this question is more appropriator on [avp.se].

Comment: @Spontifixus This would seem to me to be a question about film recording techniques, which is listed in the first bullet point of AVP's on-topic list. What makes you think it's off-topic?

Comment: On Stack Exchange, decisions like this are made by the community via rough-consensus democracy rather than moderators. The moderators volunteer their time to assist, not to rule. Previous community discussion on whether video questions are on topic is at http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/28/can-i-ask-videography-related-questions/33, and you're welcome to continue in that conversation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See "Shooting with the AF Lock" on p94 of the [user manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/4/0300005134/01/PS_SX220HS_SX230HS_CUG_EN.pdf).  This is linked from p120 which is for shooting movies so I would assume it works for movies as well as stills.

Comment: That's it. The german user manual I downloaded from Canon just had some 36 pages, which didn't cover that particular topic...

Comment: You probably got the "Getting started" guide, rather than the user manual :-)

Comment: FYI the full manual is available in German too if you prefer: http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/7/0300005137/01/PS_SX220HS_SX230HS_CUG_DE.pdf